# Nginx Passenger Not Visible Application Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

I have: 
    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
    ruby-1.9.3-p194
    Rails 3.2.7

I am trying to get access to my Rails application through Nginx + Passenger.

**/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf** file is:

```
user  test;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.14;
    passenger_ruby /home/test/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  10.11.11.178;

        root /efiling/public;
        passenger_enabled on;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
....
```

When I enter a link **10.11.11.178** I get **Welcome to nginx!**
But I am expecting to get Rails app default page.

What is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

---

@Jashwant. First, I removed line as was mentioned by @Brandon. Second, I removed index.html file from my_app\public folder.

Comment: Your request goes to `location / {`. Useful links: http://nginx.org/r/location and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: Thanks. But What should I do? Remove **location** from config?

Comment: You should provide your full config. Until that It's hard to say definitely. [Reading manual](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html) also would be a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the following from the config:

> ```
>     location / {
>         root   html;
>         index  index.html index.htm;
>     }
> ```

Comment: It doesn't help me. When I remove that peace of code I get 404 error.

Comment: @LeshaPipiev, I get the 404 error and internal server error at another config. How you finally solved this issue ?